# scope_identity throwing System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I understand what the error means (your trying to store a number bigger than int in an int) but can't see where this is coming from.

Because of the mention of IDENTITY in the error, I'm **assuming** its the call to scope_identity() that's problematic.  I understand that it returns decimal(38,0) but my table **should** never return a PK that is not an int.

I've just started receiving this last week after this code has run for months.

Help!!!!!

I have a table with this PK

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[plan_languages](
    [plan_language_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
....
)
```

and a stored proc that returns the newly created PK

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[sp_plan_languages_insert] (
....,
,@new_pk INT = 0 OUTPUT
)
...
INSERT INTO dbo.plan_languages ( ... )
VALUES ( ... )
SET @new_pk = scope_identity()
```

and c# code that executes that stored proc and retrieves that PK

```
        private int InsertPlanLanguage(PlanLanguageDTO language)
        {
            int pk = 0;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DbConnetionString))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.sp_plan_languages_insert";
....
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@new_pk", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, DbType = DbType.Int32 });


                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (cmd.Parameters["@new_pk"].Value != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            pk = (int)cmd.Parameters["@new_pk"].Value;
                        }
                    }
```

and I should have plenty of room

```
SELECT MAX(l.plan_language_id) from dbo.plan_languages l
```

returns 190891

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SELECT MAX(l.plan_language_id) from dbo.plan_languages l

This isn't relevant: it returns the *current* maximum value of the plan_language_id column.  The next identity value is not necessarily MAX(id)+1 since rows may have been deleted.

Try:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT(plan_languages)
```

[DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) also has an option to reseed the identity value.  Though presumably you'll hit the same problem again after running for another few months of inserting and deleting rows.

Comment: duh!!! it was actually a child table that has hit its max: Checking identity information: current identity value '2147483647', current column value '2147483647'

Answer (score 0):

Type casting the return value of SQL functions that return an identity to int usually fails for me.  I think because System.Data.SqlClient treats the value as decimal.  Try doing this instead.

```
pk = Convert.ToIn32(cmd.Parameters["@new_pk"].Value);
```